# Obj-C / Using MapKitView and TableView together with delegation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, mapkit

I am a very beginner of objective c and I wanted to create a scene about using 2 child view controller in a master view controller which includes MapKit and TableView. I ve searched it on internet for 1 day and but I couldn't make any of solutions since I failed in different steps of each suggestions. I know that there are a lot of way to pass data between View Controllers and I thought the best way is using delegation logic in this situation. (let me know if I am wrong please). By the way, I can update or move the cursor onto specific location WHEN I set a dummy button on MapKitViewController, so MapKit part is not where I am failing at. I am pretty sure that the problem is about communication between 2 View Controllers which are active at the same time.

**Problem:**

- Updating MapView by clicking a table row of TableView which includes location coordinate detail. Both children view are set on a MasterViewController by 2 container views.

**Tried so far:**

- Created a method "*`goToLocation:(Location*) location`*" in MapViewController and sent parameters to this method from TableViewController. =>(***Lat and Long parameters received by goToLocation() but MapKitView doesn't get updated***)
- Tried to create a delegate logic between MapView and TableView.=>(***Probably I couldn't create it properly. Please see below***)

**What I want :**

- I want to know what part I am doing wrong. Is there a easy or proper way to achieve that ?

**TableViewController.h**

```
@class TableViewController;                 //define class

@protocol TableViewDelegate <NSObject>      //define delegate protocol

//define delegate method to be implemented within another class
- (void) locationSelected: (TableViewController *) sender object:(Location *) location;

@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TableViewDelegate> delegate; //define TableViewVCDelegate as delegate
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self notifyNow:[_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

- (void) notifyNow:(Location *) location {
    //this will call the method implemented in your other class
    [self.delegate locationSelected:self object:(Location *) location];

    NSLog(@"Selected: %@",[location name]);    
}
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
//make it a delegate for TableViewVCDelegate
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <TableViewDelegate>
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    _tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
    _tableViewController.delegate = self; //set its delegate to self somewhere
}

!!_ This Method Doesn't Get Triggered _!!
- (void)locationSelected:(TableViewController *)sender object:(Location *)location {
    NSLog(@"%@ is great!", [location name]);
}
```

**MainViewController.m (Master/Root View Controller)**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topCont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomCont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *safeArea;


@end

@implementation MainViewController

MapViewController *mapViewVC;
TableViewController *tableViewVC;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    tableViewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
    mapViewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TopChildVC"];

    [self addChildViewController:tableViewVC];
    [tableViewVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                         0.0f,
                                         self.safeArea.frame.size.width,
                                         self.safeArea.frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.bottomCont addSubview:tableViewVC.view];
    [tableViewVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self addChildViewController:mapViewVC];
    [mapViewVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                         0.0f,
                                         self.safeArea.frame.size.width,
                                         self.safeArea.frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.topCont addSubview:mapViewVC.view];
    [mapViewVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: `_tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc]init];` That's creating a whole new `TableViewController` object, not the one you think of. If you do `NSLog(@"Table in MapVC: %@", _tableViewController);` just after it, and do `NSLog(@"Table in MainVC: %@", tableViewVC");` in the `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController` you'll see that the address are different (the "0xaaaa" stuff printed).

Comment: Remove your two lines in `viewDidLoad` of `MapViewController.m`. Instead, just after `mapViewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TopChildVC"];`, do `tableViewVC.delegate = mapViewVC`

Comment: @Larme I removed those 2 lines from didLoad of MapViewController.m and added those 2 lines you wrote, but this time `Table in MainVC: <TableViewController: 0x7ff2a9a107e0>` and `Table in MapVC: (null)` logged. I didn't understand how could `tableViewVC.delegate = mapViewVC` work, before we instantiate `tableViewVC`, because `tableViewVC` is null already. I don't know how to receive same TableViewVC addresses by instantiate it from 2  different view controllers.